# Incomplete/cropped entries in google app engine logs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gae-module

While looking through my appengine standard python app logs, I started noticing entries with no response status/data declared

> 162.158.92.77 - - [19/May/2017:17:18:20 +0300] "GET /v1/projects/explore/ HTTP/1.1" - - - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel
>   Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36" "mysite.com" ms=1735 cpu_ms=0
>   cpm_usd=0 loading_request=0 instance=- app_engine_release=- trace_id=-

while normally It looks like this:

> 162.158.92.77 - - [19/May/2017:21:01:23 +0300] "GET /v1/projects/explore/ HTTP/1.1" **200 1957** - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;
>   Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36" "mysite.com" ms=246 cpu_ms=257
>   cpm_usd=0.000050218711 loading_request=0
>   instance=00c61b117c2752cca1f10e8bd589dd3000affdfeadfda69c46d60d77771c158a00602f746544
>   app_engine_release=1.9.48 trace_id=-

Such empty/cropped log entries use "info" level with no warnings/errors showed. Any ideas/explanations please?